# A3 Arrays of movieClips

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, movieclip

[AS3.0] I'm currently working on my graduation diploma and I have a problem with managing movieClips with the same instance name..sort of. I'm creating an array of objects with this Class an Arrays in frame 1:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class createFractionBuilding
    {
        public function createFractionBuilding(_fractionBuildingMovieClip:MovieClip, _fractionBuildingLevel:Number,_fractionBuildingCost:Number, _fractionBuildingFrame:Number)
        {
            fractionBuildingLevel = _fractionBuildingLevel;
            fractionBuildingCost = _fractionBuildingCost;
            fractionBuildingMovieClip = _fractionBuildingMovieClip
            fractionBuildingFrame = -fractionBuildingFrame
        }

        public var fractionBuildingLevel:Number,fractionBuildingCost:Number,fractionBuildingFrame:Number;
        public var fractionBuildingMovieClip:MovieClip
    }
}
```

On main timeline I'm refering to this Class by creating an Array of objects:

```
var allHumanBuildingsList:Array = new Array();

var humanCapitolBuildingProperties:createFractionBuilding = new createFractionBuilding(humanCapitol_mc,1,1000,1);
var humanCastleBuildingProperties:createFractionBuilding = new createFractionBuilding(humanCastle_mc,2,1000,1);

allHumanBuildingsList.push(humanCapitolBuildingProperties);
allHumanBuildingsList.push(humanCastleBuildingProperties);
```

For this to work I have to have movieclip called "humanCapitol_mc" or "humanCastle_mc" in this frame (1).

But in frame (2) I want to refer to this movieClip with such function:

```
function humanBuildingLevelCheck()
{
    for (var a:Number = 0; a < allHumanBuildingsList.length; a++)
    {
        trace (String(allHumanBuildingsList[a].fractionBuildingMovieClip))
        if (allHumanBuildingsList[a].fractionBuildingLevel == 2){
            allHumanBuildingsList[a].fractionBuildingMovieClip.gotoAndStop(3)
        } else if (allHumanBuildingsList[a].fractionBuildingLevel == 1){
            allHumanBuildingsList[a].fractionBuildingMovieClip.gotoAndStop(2)
        }
    }
}
humanBuildingLevelCheck()
```

(Each MovieClip on first frame is blank, on second is one picture, on third is different one)

Everything works, when the array creation code is in frame two, but it won't work the way I want: first I create variables and objects and then I change it's values dynamically. Do you have an idea, how could that work?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. What do you mean by `first I create variables and objects and then I change it's values dynamically.` ? Is this what you have currently or what you want ? And what does that even mean ?

Comment: Later on I want to manage and change values - for example:

allHumanBuildingsList[1].fractionBuildingLevel = 3

Sorry for unclear description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it global. If one variable is declared in keyframe 1, you can't see it in keyframe 2 but if you declare it in one layer that has only one keyframe then it will be visible anywhere within that timeline.